# Is it possible to queue commands in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

Is it possible to queue up commands? For example, (this is extremely contrived), could I type something like:

```
:vsp, q
```

To open a vertical split and then quit it immediately?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can execute more than one command by placing a | between two commands.

For example:

```
%s/htm/html/c | %s/JPEG/jpg/c | %s/GIF/gif/c
```

Source: [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Multiple_commands_at_once)

Answer (score 4):

You [can](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Multiple_commands_at_once), use a `|` between the commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `:help vsplit`, you'll see that there's an optional `+cmd` argument.

For example:

```
:vsplit +delete
```

will do a vertical split, and then run `:delete` immediately.

You can do the same thing with `vim +cmd` on the command-line and with commands like `:tabnew`.